# Vscode сделал изи папки C:/Users/$username$ GIT репозиторий

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Vscode сделал из папки C:/Users/$username$ GIT репозиторий, теперь фиксирует оттуда изменения.

Появилось после редактирования настроек (указал путь к php у расширения PHP IntelliSence)

Как теперь убрать?
[image: скрин]

Консоль гит

```html
Используется git 2.19.1.windows.1 из C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
> git rev-parse --show-toplevel
> git config --get commit.template
Open repository: c:\Users\derof
> git status -z -u
> git show :AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
> git ls-files --stage -- AppData/Roaming/Code/User/
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git show :AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
> git ls-files --stage -- AppData/Roaming/Code/User/
> git check-ignore -z --stdin
> git show :.gitconfig
> git show :.node_repl_history
> git show :.gitconfig
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git branch
> git rm --cached -r -- .
fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files
> git show :AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json
> git ls-files --stage -- AppData/Roaming/Code/User/
```

Comment: удалите папку .git

Comment: в C:/Users/$username$ есть только файл .gitconfig, папки нет

Comment: Значит там нет git репозитория